# Copying a file with another name

Tags: python

I want to copy `/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/swbuild/board/test_new.html` as `/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/sw_admin/reports/board/test.html` ,overwrite `test.html` if it already exists..is there an inbuilt python copy command to do this?

```
/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/swbuild/board/test_new.html
/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/sw_admin/reports/board/test.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`shutil.copy`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy):

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/swbuild/board/test_new.html',
            '/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/sw_admin/reports/board/test.html')
```